# PouchDB: is a destroy clean while doing live replication?

Tags: ionic-framework, synchronization, pouchdb, destroy

I am having data corruption in my mobile app (Ionic 1), in very occasional cases.

The app is working with users logging to a remote CouchDB server. Each user has its own db in the server. There is only one session at a time in the app, but it may happen that user A uses the app, logs out, then user B logs in to use the app.

Locally, the app has one unique PouchDB, which is created on login, then live-synchronized with the user's remote couchDB, then destroyed on logout.

Problem: in very random and unfrequent cases that I cannot reproduce, some data of user A appear in the data of user B! and more over, some data of user A are destroyed (maybe transferred to B, not sure).

So, I was wondering what happens if I call `PouchDB.destroy` while a live sync is running (`PouchDB.replicate` with options `{ live: true, retry:true, continuous:true }` in both ways: local to remote and remote to local). Is `destroy` doing something to cleanly stop the replication? If not, it might explain that some data are transferred from old-local A database to new-local B database (I have tried to browse the PouchDB source code but got lost in it. I could just see that `Replication.cancel` is called from its `onDestroy` method, but not sure it handles things right for my case).

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: What happens once a user logs out? Do you `cancel` the replication?

Comment: No I don't. I just call destroy() (which apparently makes 'cancel' called on the replication, but not sure)

Comment: Hmm I'd try to `cancel` the replication first and `destroy` the db afterwards. Worst case is: Your code just became a little more readable as you're not calling `cancel` implicitly anymore. Best case: Your problem is solved ;)

Comment: Sure, and thanks. But I am almost sure it will only make the code more readable. The cancel method just sets a flag to true, so I believe the replication goes on in the background. Maybe a safer approach would be to way the replication to complete once the cancellation is triggered, but this might be endless if there is no network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safest way to destroy a database during replication is to first call `cancel()` and then wait for the `complete` event. For instance:

```js
var sync = db.sync(otherDB, {live: true, retry: true});
sync.on('complete', function () {
  db.destroy().then(/* ... */);
});
/* ... */
sync.cancel(); // will trigger a 'complete'
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Many thanks, will try that! And do you think that NOT doing that (i.e. calling cancel + waiting for it to complete) would explain my data corruption issue?

Comment: I have done several tests, it looks like it works safer/better now. Hard to be 100% sure as the issue is random though. I think the most important thing is to way for the sync to complete, before destroying the local DB. I also had an issue in my superlogin config, where the endpoint did not include the ":3000" port reference, causing logouts to fail (see #2 issue of superlogin on gitgub). Not sure how this could impact...